# How to create a Dot Lock Screen in iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ipad

i want to create a Dot Lock Screen in my application similar to present in Android.

This lock screen should remember the previous movement of my finger so that if i perform the same movement again then it show the success message.

How can i do this?

Is there any opensource application available for this?

Comment: Follow this one http://blog.sallarp.com/android-style-unlock-screen-for-iphone-apps-using-quartz-2d/#more-956